# How to add a new field to oscar dashboard

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-oscar

After following various examples here on stackoverflow my new field isn't showing up on django oscar dashboard here are my models and dashboard fork.

*catalogue* 
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct


class Product(AbstractProduct):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')


from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

*dashboard/catalogue/forms.py*

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue import forms as base_forms


class ProductForm(base_forms.ProductForm):

    class Meta(base_forms.ProductForm.Meta):

        fields = ('file',)
```

I am wondering what i did wrong for people that have faced this issue before I need help. thanks.

Comment: Have you forked the main dashboard (`oscar.ashboard`) app as well? You need to do that before you fork `oscar.dashboard.catalogue`.

Comment: Yes I did fork the main Oscar dashboards